# Command line failing with https

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet, ssl

I'm a bit new when it comes to networking. As a disclaimer, I installed Chrubuntu. The OS was able to connect fine, but it had an unrelated error and required an install and upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.

I can open any https and http site in a browser. I can call updates and sites with apt-get update, curl, and wget. However these commands plus easy_install and pip don't work when dealing with https.

What can I do?  I've seen a few questions with the output of ifconfig so here's that:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:00:00:0f:97:b6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e200:ff:fe0f:97b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30020 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38429042 (38.4 MB)  TX bytes:2171804 (2.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:49893 (49.8 KB)  TX bytes:49893 (49.8 KB)
```

Comment: It problem is not related with ifconfig. I want to see exactly your command line you prompted with easy_install and pip.

Comment: ^^Agreed. Edit the question to remove the ifconfig bit, and instead provide the commands that actually failed.